# Call an object method when a PHP script is done

Tags: php, object

If I have instantiated an object, is there a possible way for it to trigger a method before php shutsdown?
example

```
class foo{
   public function sayBye(){
       echo 'bye';
   }
}
$obj = new foo();
$obj2 = new foo();
die();
```

Is there a way I could automatically trigger the sayBye function? (in otherwords that code would output "byebye")

Comment: you can add a destructor: `__destruct()` to the class `foo`

Comment: this is a simplification, the script may end unexpectedly through a fatal error, or maybe it will be a temporary object in a function call...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about putting a call to `sayBye()` in the destructor?

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [register_shutdown_function](http://php.net/register_shutdown_function) function.

Comment: This will solve the problem in the most efficient way, but I'd like to issue a warning against using this method in bigger projects as at least I would've forgotten about that register_shutdown_function().

Answer (score 1):

> If I have instantiated an object, is there a possible way for it to trigger a method before php shutsdown? example

There is. Check out [__destruct()](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) for more on that. Do note, however, that this is *not* reliable: if your script contains `die()`, an uncaught exception, a fatal error, the `__destruct()` will *not* be called.

You can use it, but use it wisely ;)

**EDIT**: it appears the `__destruct( )` will be called when you call `exit;`. Nonetheless, the warning still goes for the other situations.

Answer (score 0):

The most easy way I can see is that you add a destructor to your class.

```
class foo{
   public function sayBye(){
       echo 'bye';
   }

   public function __destruct(){
       $this->sayBye();
   }
}
```

What will this do? When script execution is done or unset($object) is called, you will execute the code within __destruct(). It will probably not work with die(), as this will stop the script hastily before the script is done.